# Sup of a linear function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

Let $X$ be a banach space or simply a normed space and $C$ a convex (closed) subset of $X$.
It is true that if $x \in C$ is such that $f(x)=\sup f(C)$, (in other words $x$ is a supporting point for $C$) where $f$ is a linear continuous function then $x$ must be in the boundary points of C?
It seems logical to me cause the growth of $f$ in each direction is linear, but I can't find a proof or a coutrexample. Can anyone help?

Comment: You meant $x\in C$. Hint: If $\lambda>1$ what is $f(\lambda x)$? Is $\lambda x\in C$?

Comment: Yeah. I meant $x \in C$. Sorry about that. Thanks for your replies. If $\lambda >1$ then $f (\lambda x)> f(x)$ and $\lambda x $ is still in $C$. So i guess that $x$ can't  be the point that  i am looking for. How can i show that then is in the boundary ? thanks.

Comment: ??? Why do you say $\lambda x\in C$? That's impossible, because $f(\lambda x)>\sup_{y\in C}f(y)$.

Comment: Ok, that's embarrassing. $\lambda x $ can't be in $C$ of course. Does that mean that $x$ is a boundary point of $C$? I can't see why ..

Comment: Do you know the _definition_ of the boundary?

Comment: Sure.. in every open ball (x centered) with radius bigger than 1 there are points that don't belong to $C$, and that's perfect for my thesis. What about radius less than 1? (it's the right way to proceed? Thanks)

Comment: Oh dear. You have the definition of the boundary wrong. Learn the definition first.

Comment: (That's assuming you meant "in every open ball ($x$ centered) with radius bigger than 1 there are points that don't belong to $C$, " as the definition.)

Comment: I do know the defintion. I thought it was pointless writing it in the comment. Anyway, if you want to help me show me the proof please!
 Thanks for your time, you're very nice.

Comment: "Anyway, if you want to help me show me the proof please!" Nope. You say you know the definition. Then you should be done. What is $||x-\lambda x||$?

Comment: Final comment: All of this has been valid assuming that $f(x)>0$. (Where did we use the fact that $f(x)>0$?) If $f(x)<0$ you need to modify the argument sightly. And to handle the case $f(x)=0$ you're going to need to get the definition of "supporting point" right - the definition in your post is not quite right (and the thing you say you want to prove is not quite true).

Comment: I just can't get it. It seems so simple. I need to show that every  every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $C$ and at least one point not of $C$. So, if the radius of $B_r(x)$ is bigger than $\lambda$ everything is ok. If $r< \lambda $ i can find only points of C and that's not ok. Where convexity of $C$ comes into play?

Comment: You didn't answer the question. What is $||x-\lambda x||$?

Comment: I need to ask "What Sup?"

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is constant, then $x$ need not be a boundary point, it can be any point of
$C$. So we can presume that $f$ is not constant.

Note that for any set $S$, a point $x \in S$ is either in the interior or
the boundary.

Now consider the point $x \in C$ in the question. Suppose $x$ is not a boundary point then it must be an interior point. Since $f$ is not constant, there
is some $h$ such that $f(x+h) > f(x)$ (that is, $f(h) >0$), and since $x$ is an interior point,
there is some $\lambda >0$ such that $x+ \lambda h \in C$, and we have
$f(x+\lambda h) = f(x) + \lambda f(h) > f(x)$, which is a contradiction.